# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MobilePayManager"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native, debugging

I know there is a lot of similar errors out there, but i tried doing exactly what the answers said, and nothing helped.

I have now even created a completely new DemoProj (React-Native app), linked the repository the error is in, and i STILL get the same error.
The repository can be found here: https://github.com/Renetnielsen/DemoProj

If one fetches it and runs xcode, and runs that, you would get the same error.
I have no solution to this what so ever, especially since im no Objective C programmer.
Please please help me!!

The module react-native-appswitch is a small 2 function module, that just exports some IOS SDK functionality (https://developer.mobilepay.dk/appswitch-integration)

**Complete Stacktrace:** https://github.com/Renetnielsen/DemoProj/blob/master/README.md

Solutions tried
 - Create completely new app, refered repo, installed, got error
 - Ran on device, same error.
 - Cleaned build folder, pods and so on - still error
 - Linking binary files and so on

It needs to be fixed using 64 bit architecture, so using 32 is not an option, since ios does not support that any more as far as i know.

Comment: I received the same type of error with a different payment SDK that would not run on a simulator (x86_64 architecture), only on a device. Have you tried building and running your app on a device?

Comment: Hi @mike. yea sadly that does not work either